# How do I make hit damage a Gaussian distribution centered around a value?

Tags: algorithm, random, distribution

I'd like my character's attacks to on average 10 damage, but to vary anywhere from 0 to 20.

Instead of a linear spread, I would like a normal distribution, so most of their hits are between 10-15, but they can still hit between 0-20. How can I do this?

I am using PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Second (harder) aproach. I used that in c# to get a gaussian distribution ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218060/random-gaussian-variables)) i think you can easly traslate in php.

```
private double  nextGaussian(double mean,double variance ) {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218060/random-gaussian-variables

            //with mean = 0.5 and variance = 0.5 we get uniform distribution over [0..1]

            double u1 = r.NextDouble(); //these are uniform(0,1) random doubles
            double u2 = r.NextDouble();
            double randStdNormal = Math.Sqrt(-2.0 * Math.Log(u1)) *
                         Math.Sin(2.0 * Math.PI * u2); //random normal(0,1)
                         //Math.Sin( Math.PI * u2); //random normal(0,1)
            double randNormal =
                         mean + variance * randStdNormal; //random normal(mean,stdDev^2)

            return randNormal;

        }
```

You can try

```
 damage = nextGaussian(0.5, 0.2) *MAXDAMAGE ;
```

and play with second parameter of nextGaussian (variance).

Here follow a test I made distributing points over x axe changing the variance :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is roll 4 dice (6 faces)  add them , then subtract 4. You get 0..20 with more distribution in the middle. Or 2 * 12 FACE dice - 2.

Comment: surely 5 * 4d rolls would be better due to no subtraction, and with a higher number of rolls (granted its only one) the distribution becomes more pronounced (less likely to get those extremes). 2 12d rolls would result in large variance in the numbers, whilst this still leans in favor of the median numbers, it would also allow the extremes to be more likely. I prefer your other answer as numbers, however this stands as a good visual representation

Comment: you're right but with 5 * 4d you miss 0..3 values requested by Thomas in his question

Comment: You are correct, using any dice system without subtraction would eliminate any number fewer than the number of dice, therefore the subtraction is a necessary stage in order to include those numbers

Answer (score 1):

Would personally suggest the following KISS technique to convert uniform distribution to slanted distribution:

Randomly (uniformly), draw a number `x` between 0 and 1.
Now raise `x`  by some const predetermined `p` value (likely) in the range  between 1.1 to 7. The larger `p` is, the more slanted (and less likely to hit extreme results) it'll be. Lets call `x` by the power of `p` our `offset coefficient`. Now randomly pick a `sign` (i.e plus or minus [negative, positive]). OK, the `center` of your desired range is 10 == the max `offset` from the center.

```
// Essentially
// center +/- offset = min/max
// 10 - 10 = 0
// 10 + 10 = 20

//  So now, you simply do in pseudo code:
small_buffer = ~ 0.1 * range;
rand   = randomize_float_between(0, 1);
coefficient = pow(rand, p);
sign   = pick_one_of_these(-1, 1);
result = center + sign * coefficient * (offset + small_buffer);
result = max(0, min(result, 20)); // Keep it in range
```

This is the simplest way to get and tweak the effect you are looking for.

Comment: +1 Good alternative. A mathematically correct Gaussian distribution is difficult to tune right, expensive to calculate, and overkill for most games.

Comment: @Anko thanks, any monotonously increasing function from (0, 1) to (0, 1) should work (assuming it's starts with `f(0) = 0` and ends with `f(1) = 1`).
For instance, instead of `x^p` we could do `(2^(x * 10) - 1) / 1023` for a possibly more extreme slant.